# Cannot display errors in php despite turning on error reporting

Tags: php, runtime-error

I'm trying to move a php/mysql web application to a new server.  The application runs fine on multiple other servers, just not the one the client wants it on.  Problem 1 is I can't get errors to display on screen or in an error log.  I have the following settings:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & E_STRICT
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
track_errors = On
error_log = /srv/www/htdocs/errorlog
```

I've used the command "service apache2 restart" to restart after I made edits.

I can't figure out why I can't get the server to display errors.  I have even put in a line with no semi colon after to see if I could trigger an error and it just shows a blank page.

This is a Amazon Web Services server if that helps.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You sure you're updating the correct `php.ini` file? Check the output of `phpinfo()` to see the location of the `php.ini` file in use (as well as any other potential config files) and the runtime settings for `error_reporting` and `display_errors`

Comment: Sigh, that was it.  I was told by the server admin where the file was and like an idiot, didn't check for myself.  Thank you.